# Implications of continuous differentiability

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider a function $f:\Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$ with $f(\theta)\geq 0$ $\forall \theta \in \Theta$. Suppose that $f(\theta)$ is continuously differentiable at $\theta_0$. I want to show that

(1) the function $(f(\theta))^2$ is differentiable at $\theta_0$

(2) if $\theta_0$ is such that $f(\theta_0)=0$ then $\frac{d f(\theta)}{\theta}|_{\theta=\theta_0}=0$

Regarding point (1), I know that, since $f(\theta)$ is differentiable at $\theta_0$, $\frac{d f(\theta)}{\theta}|_{\theta=\theta_0}$ is well-defined. Hence, by the chain rule, also $\frac{d (f(\theta))^2}{\theta}|_{\theta=\theta_0}$ is well-defined. However, since we are in a multi-dimensional case, this does not imply that $(f(\theta))^2$ is differentiable at $\theta_0$. Could you help me to formalise this last step?

Regarding point (2), by the definition of partial derivative, $\frac{d f(\theta)}{\theta_i}|_{\theta=\theta_0}:=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\theta_0+he_i)-f(\theta_0)}{h}$ where $e_i:=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ with $1$ at the $i$the position, for $i=1,...,l$. I don't know how to proceed from here to show that $\frac{d f(\theta)}{\theta}|_{\theta=\theta_0}=0$

Comment: How can a function have a "well defined" derivative without being differentiable?

Comment: See the section differentiability in higher dimension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function

Comment: I know, but that doesn't answer my question.  A function is "differentiable" if and only if it "has a derivative".  Yes, a function can fail to be differentiable even if its **partial derivatives** are well defined, but if a function has a "well defined" derivative, then it is necessarily differentiable.

Comment: ok, I see now, thanks a lot!!